# WPF ListBox Databinding & Events

Tags: c#, wpf, events, listbox, binding

My problem is rather simple.

I have a ListBox, containing Thumnails (Image)

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox_Thumbnails" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding Source= {StaticResource ThumbnailListSource}}" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-1,26,0,54">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=absolutePath}" MouseLeftButtonDown=<!--?????-->/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I wanted to show an image, but as a new StackOverFlow user, I can't. You can find the image here:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/61aa983cad.jpg

(For those who don't trust me, I explain here the content of the image:
On the left, there is a list of thumbnails (displayed vertically) and on the right there is a bigger image, corresponding per default to a large image of the first thumbnail).

When I click on a thumbnail (on the left), the large image on the right should be updated by the one that I clicked on.

As I am new with WPF, my approach is perhaps totally wrong with the ListBox.
Please, WPF Gurus, show me the light!

Comment: As a side note the image he linked (http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/61aa983cad.jpg) is completely SFW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, you can use events on ListBox, smth like SelectionChanged... but that's totally not the TRUE WPF-Jedi way -- remember, code-behind is the dark side! =)

Think data binding, that's the Force. Bind your large Image element's source to the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox`. It should look like

```
<Image Source="{Binding SelectedItem.absolutePath, ElementName=ListBox_Thumbnails}">
```

P.S. Every WPF-databinding-jedi should have [this cheat sheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf) nearby.

P.P.S. Actually, as you're using ItemTemplate this might not work, you'll have your StackPanel as the selected item... in this case you can try [the SelectedValuePath trick](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=9), set it to "absolutePath" and bind the large image to the `SelectedValue` property.

So your ListBox opening tag becomes:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox_Thumbnails" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding Source= {StaticResource ThumbnailListSource}}" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-1,26,0,54" SelectedValuePath="absolutePath">
```

And your large image tag becomes:

```
<Image Source="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=ListBox_Thumbnails}">
```

Comment: Thank you WPF Yoda Master (aka Yacoder). I will try now your "P.P.S". Unfortunately, I can't vote up your answer now as I don't have enough "rep". I will do it later. Promise!

Comment: I don't quite understand. It would be great if you could provide some code! Thank you!