# WPF/C# Click on image thumbnail -> show that image big

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, thumbnails

I have images coming in from a camera (but for now suppose they're on disk).
I want these as a list of thumbnails:

```
[thumb1] [thumb2] [thumb3] ... [thumb100]
```

When a thumbnail is clicked, I want that image put on a large image view on the UI (same window). Sort of like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206817/wpf-listbox-databinding-events).

I'm a C# noob and can't follow that answer to get this working :(

Also, plot twist: I also want to have a "live mode" on my camera, which means the "big image" UI element must also be able to show images straight from camera in real time (no thumbnails during "live mode").

Here is the code I got so far. What else do I need to add?

XML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <!--This is the big image that I want to see when I click each thumbnail: -->
    <Image Source="{Binding BigImage}"/>

    <!--This is the thumbnail chain at the bottom: -->
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Thumbnails}"  Height="100">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding BigImage}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    </ListBox>

</StackPanel>
```

CS:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // this is the big image on the UI
    public ImageSource BigImage { get; set; }

    // this is a collection of thumbnails. When clicked, that image should become
    // the "big image"
    public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> Thumbnails { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        Thumbnails = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>();
        Thumbnails.Add(BigImage);
        Thumbnails.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Raw0.bmp")));
        Thumbnails.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Raw1.bmp")));
        Thumbnails.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Raw2.bmp")));
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Thumbnails");
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigImage is not a property of ImageSource. The Source of the Image control needs to be bound to the datacontext itself. Do that by using a dot.

```
<Image Source="{Binding .}"/>
```

Then bind the SelectedItem of the ItemsControl to the BigImage object.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Thumbnails}" SelectedItem="{Binding BigImage}" Height="100">
```